# typedef struct pointer definition

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef, declaration

I'm pretty new in C and having some problems with all the pointer stuff.

I wrote this code:

```
typedef struct edgeitem
{
    double          weight;
}EDGE_ITEM, *pEDGE_ITEM; //also declaration of a pointer

/************ edge that includes a pointer to the edge item, next and prev ******/
typedef struct edge
{
    pEDGE_ITEM  *edge_item;  
    pEDGE       *next;      //pointer to next edge
    pEDGE       *prev;      //pointer to prev edge
}EDGE, *pEDGE;
```

I get an error this way and just cant understand why.

I know that `edgeitem` and `edge` are tags and I can use `struct edge *next` but I declared the pointers so how come i can't use them?

Do i need to use * if I have a pointer?

```
pEDGE_ITEM *edge_item
//or
pEDGE_ITEM edge_item
```

I cant understand, it's a pointer so why do I add the *?

And the last question is:
If I'm using the above, what's the difference between:

```
*EDGE  next
EDGE  *next
```

and last one :
if I'm adding:

```
typedef struct edge_list
{
    EDGE        *head;
}EDGE_LIST;
```

is it the same as :

```
pEDGE      head;
```

Comment: It is generally considerd bad style to hide a '*' behind a typedef. It can only lead to confusion. Programmers read *thing faster than pThing. The same goes for other syntax elements, such as `#define AND &&`, et cetera. In short: don't do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot use pEDGE within the definition of the struct. You shoud do something like:

```
typedef struct edge {
    pEDGE_ITEM          *edge_item;  
    struct edge         *next;      //pointer to next edge
    struct edge         *prev;      //pointer to prev edge
} EDGE, *pEDGE;
```

You must also note that `edge_item` is a double pointer. You also mention that in your question. So if you use `pEDGE_ITEM` and you just want to have a normal pointer you should not write `pEDGE_ITEM *edge_item` but just `pEDGE_ITEM edge_item`.

For clarifying, all the following declarations are equivalent:

```
struct edgeitem *edge_item;
EDGE_ITEM *edge_item;
pEDGE_ITEM edge_item;
```

But

```
pEDGE_ITEM *edge_item;
```

is equivalent to

```
struct edgeitem **edge_item;
EDGE_ITEM **edge_item;
```

About `*EDGE next` that is wrong syntax. The correct syntax would be `EDGE* next` or `pEDGE next`. So once `struct edge` is defined you can just use any of these two, but while defining the struct, you must do as I show at the beginning of my answer.

Yes, the following two definitions are equivalent:

```
typedef struct edge_list {
    EDGE        *head;
} EDGE_LIST;

typedef struct edge_list {
    pEDGE        head;
} EDGE_LIST;
```

Comment: I saw that in both answers you wrote to use "struct edge" , how come that this is correct while pEdge isn't? this is also undefined ?

Comment: because you cannot use neither `EDGE` nor `pEDGE` typedefs until the struct is fully defined. Once it is, you can freely use the typedefs instead of using the longer `struct edge` or `struct edge *`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a type alias before it is defined.  Using the structure tag is a workaround:

```
typedef struct edge
{
    EDGE_ITEM    *edge_item;  
    struct edge  *next;      //pointer to next edge
    struct edge  *prev;      //pointer to prev edge
} EDGE;
```

Note that you almost surely used the pointer aliases incorrectly, I avoided them.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work fine.

```
    typedef struct edgeitem
    {
       double          weight;
    }EDGE_ITEM, *pEDGE_ITEM; //also declaration of a pointer

    /************ edge that includes a pointer to the edge item, next and prev ******/
    typedef struct edge *pEDGE;  //<<-------  this
    typedef struct edge
    {
       pEDGE_ITEM  *edge_item;  
       pEDGE       *next;      //pointer to next edge
       pEDGE       *prev;      //pointer to prev edge
    }EDGE;
```